# AWS cdk running locally using sam

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have a CDK app which I generate template.yml file using:

```
cdk synth --no-staging > ./template.yml
```

and then run sam local:

```
sam local start-api
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sam", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 166, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 124, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 41, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/cli/main.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/local/start_api/cli.py", line 94, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/local/start_api/cli.py", line 192, in do_cli
    service = LocalApiService(lambda_invoke_context=invoke_context, port=port, host=host, static_dir=static_dir)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/local/lib/local_api_service.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.api_provider = ApiProvider(lambda_invoke_context.stacks, cwd=self.cwd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/providers/api_provider.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.api = self._extract_api()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/providers/api_provider.py", line 64, in _extract_api
    provider.extract_resources(self.stacks, collector, cwd=self.cwd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/providers/cfn_api_provider.py", line 73, in extract_resources
    self._extract_cfn_gateway_v2_route(stack.stack_path, resources, logical_id, resource, collector)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/providers/cfn_api_provider.py", line 315, in _extract_cfn_gateway_v2_route
    method, path = self._parse_route_key(route_key)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.37.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/providers/cfn_api_provider.py", line 488, in _parse_route_key
    [method, path] = route_key.split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

and ideas what's the issue?

Comment: Seems like one of the issues here is having a Websocket Api which does not work, try to comment out the Websocket api and see if it works.

Comment: so it seems like local testing is not possible with so many limitations it's not ready yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you have an older version of AWS SAM. I have multiple projects that implement AWS CDK and use AWS SAM for local testing and they work without any issues!

Your AWS SAM version seems to be `1.37.0`, try to upgrade to the latest version and see if that allows you to use the two together.

As a reference point: one of my projects uses AWS CDK version `2.53.0` with AWS SAM version `1.78.0`.

Comment: thank you @AdamE, I updated all the versions and disabled websocket module in my cdk, and it works now however, I am not sure how to configure the Amplify.configure library to use my local SAM instance. 

`Amplify.configure({
      Auth: {
        region,
        userPoolId,
        userPoolWebClientId,
      },
});`

Comment: Glad it works now! I think you're best off considering this question answered and ask the Amplify question as a separate question (sorry, I'm not familiar with it!) or search Stack Overflow for a similar issue.